# Trouble to understand why this palindrome method works

Tags: ruby

Below is a palindrome method that works correctly:

```
def palindrome?(string)
  i = 0
  while i < string.length
    if string[i] != string[(string.length - 1) - i]
      return false
    end

    i += 1
  end

  return true
end

# These are tests to check that your code is working. After writing
# your solution, they should all print true.

puts('palindrome?("abc") == false: ' + (palindrome?('abc') == false).to_s)
puts('palindrome?("abcba") == true: ' + (palindrome?('abcba') == true).to_s)
puts('palindrome?("z") == true: ' + (palindrome?('z') == true).to_s)
puts('palindrome?("2220222") == true: ' + (palindrome?('2220222') == true).to_s)
puts('palindrome?("2220922") == false: ' + (palindrome?('2220922') == false).to_s)
```

Here are the things I cannot understand:

a) How can this method ever return `false` if the expression `return true` outside of the while loop always returns `true` after the loop is finished, overriding any previous `return false` statements?

b) In case of a false palindrome such as 2220922, why does while loop return `false` even though the last iteration (string[5] ! = string[0]) compares 2 to 2,  which should evaluate to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the same question really.
Return false will quit the method and return false, it never gets to return true.

That will only happen when two characters don't match

So for 2220922
It compares

```
2     2 in the first pass
 2   2  in the next
  2 9    in the 3rd and returns false.
```

3rd pass i = 2 so that's 7 - 1 - 2 = 4 and the 4th char in the string is 9

An alternative that would make the behaviour clearer would be

```
def palindrome?(string)
  result = true
  i = 0
  while (i < string.length) && result
    result = string[i] != string[(string.length - 1) - i]
    i += 1
  end

  return result
end
```

Saying all that you do know that string == string.reverse would work?

Comment: Thanks, Tony. I did not know return quits the method. Now it all makes sense!

Comment: There's a school of thought that says you should only have one return in a function. I'm not anal about it, it can give you a huge amount of nesting, but it's a good idea to see if it makes the code more readable.

Comment: Yes, I knew string == string.reverse would also work. I am doing some beginner exercises and I´m trying to build as much as possible without using built-in methods (just for the sake of learning, of course)

Comment: Small typo: "And alternative...". Will delete this comment when you've seen it.